# Images not showing on my localhost with Docker php image (htaccess issue and adaptive-images tool)

Tags: php, docker, image, apache, .htaccess

I have a problem with an old website that uses a php tool that adapts the images according to the resolution of the device. The tool is called **adaptive-images**, which has been dormant for many years, but still works fine.

Here is the **github** link to the tool:

https://github.com/MattWilcox/Adaptive-Images

**apaptative-images.php**

https://github.com/MattWilcox/Adaptive-Images/blob/master/adaptive-images.php

The problem is that I want to have that page locally to manage it and the images are not visible. I have always had the website locally with **wamp (windows)** and it has never given any problems, but now I want to do it with Linux and **Docker (php+apache)**, but the images are not displayed and I think the problem may be due to the php configuration of the server. When I remove the **adaptive-images** part of the code from the **.htaccess**, the images load perfectly. This is the **htaccess** code:

```
# Adaptive-Images -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Add any directories you wish to omit from the Adaptive-Images process on a new line, as follows:
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !some-directory
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !another-directory

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !assets

# Send any GIF, JPG, or PNG request that IS NOT stored inside one of the above directories
# to adaptive-images.php so we can select appropriately sized versions

RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|png)$ adaptive-images.php

# END Adaptive-Images -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know there are newer tools (**srcset**) to do this (the same developer warns it in the documentation), but adaptive-images still works perfectly and I don't want to change it for now. It works on external servers without problems, also on **wamp (Windows)** with **php 7.4**, but in **Docker's php-apache (version 8.1.5)** it doesn't work and I think the problem could be in some php component. I can access all the php settings to change it, but I would like to know where the problem would be.

The Docker image I have installed (version 8.1.5):

https://hub.docker.com/_/php

**EDIT:**

I think I have identified the problem, it is when activating the **mod-rewrite** (I need it to load blog posts). If I activate it the images disappear. Can someone help me to identify the reason?

**.htaccess:**

```
  ## Default .htaccess file
    
    
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    
    
    RewriteBase /
    
    
    RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]  
    
  RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /alone.php?url=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /alone\.php\?url=(.+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^alone\.php$ /%1/? [L,R=301]  

    
    # Adaptive-Images -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    # Add any directories you wish to omit from the Adaptive-Images process on a new line, as follows:
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !some-directory
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !another-directory
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !assets
    
    # Send any GIF, JPG, or PNG request that IS NOT stored inside one of the above directories
    # to adaptive-images.php so we can select appropriately sized versions
    
    RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|png)$ adaptive-images.php
    
    
    
    # END Adaptive-Images -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    
    
    </IfModule>
    
    
    
    
    <ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    
      mod_gzip_on Yes
      mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
      mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
      mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
      mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
      mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
      mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
      mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
    </ifModule>
```

When I remove the adaptive-images part of the **htaccess** it loads all the images, but of course the tool stops working.

Comment: What console network tab says about these images? Wrong path? Images does not exists in docker (forgot to add into image?)

Comment: The truth is that it is strange, it says:

Status Code: 200 OK

But I don't know if I'm looking in the correct console tab, do you mean Network/Img/Headers? Thanks

Comment: Justinas, I think I have identified the problem, it is when activating the mod-rewrite (I need it to load blog posts). If I activate it the images disappear. Can someone help me to identify the reason?

Comment: If you think it could be related to mod_rewrite/`.htaccess` then you need to include your complete code.

Comment: MrWhite, I have added the content of my htaccess to my question. Let's see if a solution can be found. Thank you very much.

Comment: "I need it to load blog posts" - But there doesn't appear to be anything relating to "blog posts" in your updated `.htaccess` file? Where exactly is this `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path?

Comment: MrWhite Sorry to copy and paste I missed a piece of code, I just edited my question. If I don't activate mod-rewrite those blog entries are not seen and if I activate it the images are lost.

Comment: Can any expert give me a hand?

Comment: I don't see anything "wrong" with the `.htaccess` file in this respect. "when activating the mod-rewrite" - what do you mean by this exactly? The way `adaptive-images.php` is being called it would seem to be dependent on mod_rewrite, so it can't be tested without (it's reading `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`). You would need to mock up a test to check whether it's really mod_rewrite that is the issue, or something with the script.